# *ngFor on ng-template outputs nothing Angular2

Tags: angular

Not sure why my *ngFor loop is printing nothing out. I have the following code in an html file:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- NGFOR ATTEMPTED HERE -- no content printed -->
        <ng-template *ngFor="let xb of tempData">
            <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1" class="accordion-toggle">
                <td>{{ xb.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ xb.email }}</td>
                <td>{{ xb.company }}</td>
                <td>{{ xb.status }}</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- other content -->
        </ng-template>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then, in my simple component I have the following:

```
import { Component }        from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-profile-exhibitors',
    templateUrl: './profile-exhibitors.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./profile-exhibitors.component.scss']
})
export class ProfileExhibitorsComponent {
    public tempData: any = [
        {
            'name': 'name1',
            'email': 'email1@gmail',
            'company': 'company',
            'status': 'Complete'
        },
        {
            'name': 'name2',
            'email': 'email2@gmail',
            'company': 'company',
            'status': 'Incomplete'
        }
    ];
    constructor() {}
}
```

When I run this code, I get zero output. Even weirder is that when I select the element using debug tools I see this:

[image]

Looks like it correctly recognizes my object, but then outputs nothing.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

I think what you want is

```ts
<ng-container *ngFor="let xb of tempData">
```

or

```ts
<ng-template ngFor let-xb [ngForOf]="tempData">
```

Comment: Thanks! And whoever designed the syntax for `ng-template` needs to be burned at the stake

Comment: Not sure what you're complaining about. It's normal Angular template syntax. They introduced `<ng-container>` to be able to use the more concise and more common `*xxx` syntax on `<template>` elements.

Comment: They made a smart decision with ng-container. That syntax is extremely unintuitive.

Comment: No, it's not ;-) `ngFor` adds a directive with the selector `ngFor`, `let-xb` makes the context of the template instantiation available within the template `[ngForOf]="tempData"` assigns `tempData` to the `ngFor` directive. That's quite common Angular2 template syntax. You should become comfortable with it. For example if you want to use `ngForTemplate` or `ngTemplateOutlet` or if you build custom structural directives like `*ngIf` and `*ngFor`.

Comment: Nice answer, solves my problem. the ng-template syntax makes no sense and is totally inconsistent with anything else in anguaar - let-xb to make a variable called xb? wtf?

Comment: What if I wanted an index?

Comment: How do we access index of ngFor if  `<ng-template></ng-template>` is inside a `<div></div>` containing 'ngFor' ?

Comment: @SarthakMaheshwari `<ng-template ngFor let-xb [ngForOf]="tempData" let-foo="index">` should make the index available in `foo`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer <br/> ng-template is inside a div having ngFor, I want to access index of ngFor inside ng-template, Your solution did not work though

Comment: @SarthakMaheshwari I think that is too complicated to solve in comments. I think it's better to create a new question. I also haven't done anything like this in a long time.

Comment: how do I skip a particular iteration or dom element with ng-template... e.g. if xb.name === 'mr. cannot be shown'?

Comment: You can add `*ngIf="xb.name === 'mr.'"` to the item inside the `*ngFor`. This would be like `<tr *ngIf="xb.name === 'mr.'"` with the example code in the question.

Answer (score 8):

For getting index as well: `<ng-template ngFor let-xb [ngForOf]="tempData" let-index="index">`