# Angular nested loop

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-template

i pull data from my mysql database with angular http and have a last field that contains data which is separated by a ";" but its only a string.

Now i want to have a single html element for each of this values.
But on top of that i want that for each record in my database.

I thought of something like this:
(Template) The Pipe turns the String into an array

```
        <li *ngFor="let form of data">

       {{form.idform_data}} - {{form.form_name}} -
         {{form.field_name}} - {{form.field_type}} -
         {{form.field_desc}} -
       <ng-template *ngFor = "let item of  {{form.field_data | splitAndGet : ";"}}">
         {{item}}
        </ng-template>
 </li>
```

But that wont work because the error is Unexpected closing tag "li"

If you need further code just tell me.

Would really appreciate some help right here!

Edit1: closed ng-template tag

Error now is Key[0] is undefined but i know that the array contains values

Edit2: Code
Data Gathering

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable }              from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response }          from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
private data;


constructor(private http:Http){
}

ngOnInit(){
  console.log("ngOnInit");
    this.getData();

}

getData(){
    console.log("fetching Data");
    this.http.get('http://192.168.178.42/getFormDbData.php')  //Pfad zur php datei
            .subscribe(response =>{ this.data = response.json()
                                console.log(JSON.stringify(response.json()))});


}
}
```

Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({ name: "splitAndGet" })
export class SplitAndGetPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(input: string, separator: string, index:number): any {
    var splitarr = input.split(separator);
    return splitarr;
  }
}
```

Edit : thanks for helping. 
 Also thanks for Downvoting that helps people like me which begin to learn something.

Comment: Paste the two lines above that

Comment: which 2 lines do you mean?

Comment: looks like you are missing closing `</ng-template>` tag

Comment: i closed it now and get Key[0] is undefined error but i know that the array contains values.

Comment: How does this pass validation `<ng-template *ngFor = "let item of  {{form.field_data | splitAndGet : ";"}}">` shouldn't it be `<ng-template *ngFor = "let item of  {{form.field_data | splitAndGet : ';'}}">`

Comment: Get the same Error because its basically the same.

Comment: can you share splitAndGet filter and input data?

Comment: You must not use interpolation in that `*ngFor`. Also, what's the reason to use `ng-template`? I'd recommend you to use `ng-container` if you don't want to render any HTML tag.

Comment: As @developer033 pointed out, you can't use `*ngFor` in combination with a `ng-template` tag, either replace it with a div or use ngFor differently as explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43177742/ngfor-on-ng-template-outputs-nothing-angular2)

Comment: TBH i dont really care about the tag i just want the data to be printed out.

Comment: Another point is that you're fetching your data async, so you either, initialize your array as `[]` or put a condition to check it, before `*ngFor` (in template).

Comment: At the Moment we are talking about a little data set which will be fetched completly. I can care about that when I know how to actually get the data.

Comment: I already explained the **undefined** error. Just read and fix it :) Another point is that you're using **double** quotes inside **double** quotes here: `...splitAndGet : ";"...`. Change it to **single** quotes... urgh! there are several mistakes in your code...

Comment: you can pls correct me for my faults i'm at the very beginning. I already fixxed the qoutes.

Comment: If you could help me to wait till data is fetched i would be grateful

Comment: The simplest way is to initialize the array in declaration: `data = [];` Also, I noticed that you're using `private`... AOT will complain once you build the production build. For variables that will be used in template, use `public` or simply *nothing*, just `data = []` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So guys i fixxed it know thanks to @developer033 
didnt knew that i dont use interpolation in the variable.

```
    <li *ngFor="let form of data">

       {{form.idform_data}} - {{form.form_name}} -
         {{form.field_name}} - {{form.field_type}} -
         {{form.field_desc}} -
        <div *ngFor = "let item of form.field_data | splitAndGet : ';'">
         <p>{{item}}</p>
     </div>
 </li>
```