# usage of ngFor with ng template in ngx-datatable-column

Tags: angular, ngfor, ngx-datatable, ng-template, ng-container

I am having a problem here where my ngFor does not show any data, although there is no stack error or something.

**I want to know how to display my array of objects -called "cldbAccounts"- which has to objects and display two properties of them in that same column.**

my code for that part

```
<ngx-datatable-column *ngIf="mode === 'contract' || mode === 'factorer'" name="CldbAccount" prob="cldbAccount">
   <ng-template let-column="column" height="200" let-onSort="sortFn" ngx-datatable-header-template>
      <span class="datatable-header-cell-wrapper">
      <span class="datatable-header-cell-label draggable" (click)="onSort()">CldbAccount</span>
      </span>
   </ng-template>
   <ng-template ngFor let-cldbAccount [ngForOf]="cldbAccounts">
      {{ cldbAccount.cldbAccount.cldbAccount }} [{{ cldbAccount.debitor.name }}]
   </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

I tried also that solutions from this answer [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43177742/ngfor-on-ng-template-outputs-nothing-angular2)  but the same problem exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem was just a typo in my code wher `prob="cldbAccount"` should be `prop="cldbAccount"`