# ng-template, mat-selection-list and ngFor

Tags: angular

I built a tooltip directive by following [this](https://netbasal.com/create-advanced-components-in-angular-e0655df5dde6) article,

I am trying to pass `templateRef` to the tooltip directive.

Below is my shared component,

at ts,

```
@Input() fieldPreferences: IFieldPreference[];
```

at html,

```
<mat-selection-list #list>
  <mat-list-option  
    *ngFor="let preference of fieldPreferences"
    [selected]="preference.selected"
    (click)="showPreferenceChanged(list)"
    [value]="preference.field">
    {{preference.field}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

At parent,

```
<mat-icon tooltip [content]="template">settings</mat-icon>

<ng-template #template>
 <field-preferences
    [fieldPreferences]="fieldPreferences"
    (selectedFields)="showPreferenceChanged($event)">
 </field-preferences>
</ng-template>
```

Tooltip is showing up with no content (i.e) `mat-list-option` is not generated. 
According to this [SO OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43177742/ngfor-on-ng-template-outputs-nothing-angular2), the problem is with `*ngFor` and `ng-template`.

I tried changing it to,

```
<mat-selection-list #list>
  <mat-list-option  ngFor let-preference [ngForOf]="fieldPreferences"
      [selected]="preference.selected"
      (click)="showPreferenceChanged(list)"
      [value]="preference.field">
      {{preference.field}}
    </mat-list-option>
  </mat-selection-list>
```

Still, tooltip is rendered with no content.

Answer (score 0):

You probably are using some old directives for `mat-select-list`. Here's how you'd create one for your case:

```
<mat-select #list [(ngModel)]="selectedField">
  <mat-option 
      *ngFor="let preference of fieldPreferences"
      (click)="showPreferenceChanged(list)"
      [value]="preference.field">
      {{preference.field}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

`selectedField` should be a property set on your ComponentClass with a value of the 'field' property of the `fieldPreference` object.

```
@Input() fieldPreferences: IFieldPreference[];
selectedField = 'One of the items from the fieldPreferences will go here';
```

`mat-option` doesn't have a `selected` property so you won't be able to use it. If you want one item already selected from the list, you could use `[(ngModel)]` and assign `selectedField` to it.

Comment: This for multi select option. The actual problem is with ngFor directive when used with ng-template. I was able to rendered field-preference component outside of ng-template, but when used with ng-template, ngFor doesn't invoke