# ng Template can not repeat the data but HTML element can display it

Tags: typescript, primeng, angular7

I want to show json data use ng template but can not show the data. But when i use HTML element like div or span it can display it

**format json**

> const arr = 
>   [
>        {
>         "date": 1,
>         "color": "normal"
>        },
>        {
>         "date": 2,
>         "color": "red"
>        },
>        {
>        "date": 3,
>        "color": "normal"
>        }
>   ]

**In TS;**

```html
dateArray: any;

public getJSON() {
     return this.http.get("../assets/eventcalendar.json")
        .pipe(map(res => res.json()));
  }

  getCalendar(){
    this.getJSON()
    .subscribe((event:any)=>{
        let getEvent = JSON.stringify(event);
        this.dateArray = JSON.parse(getEvent);
        console.log('this.dateArray', this.dateArray);
    })

  }
```

**In HTML: (This template can not show the json data)**

```html
<p-calendar (onSelect)="select($event)" [inline]="true" selectionMode="multiple" readonlyInput="true">
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-item="dateArray">
    <span 
      [ngClass]="item.color">
      {{item.tgl}}
    </span>
  </ng-template>
</p-calendar>
```

**In HTML: (This template can show the json data but the calendar UI not good)**

```html
<p-calendar (onSelect)="select($event)" [inline]="true" selectionMode="multiple" readonlyInput="true">
  <ng-template pTemplate="body">
    <span *ngFor="let item of dateArray"
      [ngClass]="item.color">
      {{item.tgl}}
    </span>
  </ng-template>
</p-calendar>
```

I am use primeng calendar for calendar and use angular 7 latest
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

@Alkim Al, try this once

> **change this to**

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-item="dateArray">
```

> **below line**

```
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="dateArray">
```

this may solve your issue. For more info [check here once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43177742/ngfor-on-ng-template-outputs-nothing-angular2)

Comment: I have try this but nothing happen.

Comment: If i only use ng-template instead element p-calendar from primeng the data show and run well. What primeng element p-calendar can not override with other data?